# convert vector<boost::shared_ptr<Foo> > to vector<Foo*> , is it possible?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have a function that takes, as an argument, an stl vector of pointers to Foo.

However, I also have objects which are shared pointers to the same class Foo. I would like to be able to call this function feeding this other objects too. Do I have to overload the function? I seem to be unable to dynamic-cast it from `vector<shared_ptr<Foo>>` to `vector<Foo*>`.

I know one can convert a shared_ptr to a pointer with the Get() method, but what about this? Any ideas?

**Update on the question**:

I have implemented the solution suggested below, but now, when declaring all the possible types for the template function, I get:

"explicit instantiation of 'void my_func(std::vector&, std::vector&) [with Ptr_Jet1 = Jet*, Ptr_Jet2 = Jet*]' but no definition available"

and the same thing for all the other combinations (for example, Ptr_Jet1 being shared_ptr instead of Jet*.

On the .cpp file, I have:

```
template<typename Ptr_Jet1, typename Ptr_Jet2>
void my_func(vector<Ptr_Jet1> vec1, vector<Ptr_Jet2> vec2){
//definition
}
```

and on the .h file, I have:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Jet> ptr_jet;

template<typename Ptr_Jet1, typename Ptr_Jet2>
void my_func(vector<Ptr_Jet1> vec1, vector<Ptr_Jet2> vec2);
//
template void my_func(vector<Jet*> vec1, vector<Jet*> vec2);
template void my_func(vector<Jet*> vec1, vector<ptr_jet> vec2);
template void my_func(vector<ptr_jet> vec1, vector<Jet*> vec2);
template void my_func(vector<ptr_jet> vec1, vector<ptr_jet> vec2);
```

I don't get what's wrong here...

Comment: I think the update should go to a different question because it is a compilation problem, your code is correct if you did not forget to #include the header in the cpp. I suggest you using an IDE, that's the most simple but Im looking into it right now, how to compile and link it properly.

Comment: Hi elelias! I've just found the answer for your compilation problem: my answer was a bit inaccurate down-there, sorry, I've corrected it. The point is you need to put the explicit template instantiations into the implementation file, NOT the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrote that function, **I would suggest templatization**, as shared_ptr has `operator*` just as you would use the raw pointers.

```
template<typename _Tp_ptr_Foo>
void your_fun(const vector<_Tp_ptr_Foo>& ); // or something alike here
```

In this situation, templatization does essentially the same as function overloading, but with templatization you avoid duplicating your code.

If you don't have control over the function, you need to convert the whole vector. If it is not more than a 1000 elements and you don't do it more than a couple hundred times, there's not much performance loss to fear about.

Unfortunately you cannot dynamic cast the one to the other as they are not related through inheritance. Although they look alike, `vector<T>` has nothing to do with `vector<U>`.

UPDATE:
I agree with Grizzly, template arguments are automatically deduced so you don't need to explicitly write that out. So you can keep calling it `your_fun(v)`.

The only thing you need to be careful with: if you work with header and code files separately, you need to [explicitly instruct the compiler that it should create both of your functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fexplicit_instantiation.htm), like this:

```
//header file:

template<typename _Tp_ptr_Foo>
void your_fun(const vector<_Tp_ptr_Foo>& ); 

template void your_fun(const vector<Foo*>& ); 
template void your_fun(const vector<shared_ptr<Foo> >& ); 

//code file:

template<typename _Tp_ptr_Foo>
void your_fun(const vector<_Tp_ptr_Foo>& )
{
  // implementation
}
```

---

UPDATE2:  (answering Elelias'es comment)

Your template declaration should look like this:

```
// header file:

template<typename _Tp1, typename _Tp2, typename _Tp3>
void your_fun(const vector<_Tp1>&, const vector<_Tp2>&, const vector<_Tp3>& );
```

After that, you have 2 options:

1. You can put the definition into a separate code file. In that case, you'll need 6 **explicit template instantiations in the implementation file** for the header, one for each combination.
2. **You can put the definition into the header** and then you don't need the 6 explicit instantiations. I would rather suggest this in this case. Although it does not separate declaration and implementation, it is not that bad solution. I have seen this approach in serious c++ libraries too, as an example you can have a look at operations.hpp in OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ideally, I would like to leave the already existing calls to the function untouched. If I promote the function to a template function, I would then have to re-write it and call it with:

myFunc<vector<Foo*> >( myVector_of_Foo )

wouldn't I?

Comment: @elelias: Calling it as myFunc(myVector_of_Foo) should work (the template type can be deduced).

Comment: Hi again,

I'm implementing your solution and something else came up. My function takes several vectors of pointers to Foo. So this means that, if I have 3 arguments , my_fun(vector1, vector2, vector3), and every one of them can contain either pointers or shared pointers, I would have to write six declarations for the templates to work, wouldn't I? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi! No problem, you do not necessarily need that, see my updated answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry to trouble you again. I still run into some little problems, I have updated the question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`shared_ptr<T>` and `T*` are different types, as such you can't simply cast from `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` to `vector<T*>`. If you really need a `vector<T*>` (meaning you can't change your function as per Barnabas Szabolcs's answer) you need to manually copy the pointer out of the source vector. Since you are using boost anyways, I assume that using `Boost.Range` is ok. If you can use C++11 this is pretty simple to do:

```
vector< shared_ptr<Foo> > foo;
auto range = foo | boost::adaptors::transform([](shared_ptr<Foo>& ptr) { return ptr.get(); };
std::vector<Foo*> bar(range.begin(), range.end());
```

This uses C++11 for the lambda function (which could be easily replaced by a functor/functionptr for c++03 code) and `auto` to save the range. IIRC the return type of the for the range transformation is unspecified in the documentation of `Boost.Range`, so hardcoding it might be a bad idea. To get rid of `auto` in c++03 code you could use  `boost::copy_range`:

```
struct transformation //using a functor instead of a plain function will enable inlining of the transformation, which is liekly benefitial for performance
{ Foo* operator()(shared_ptr<Foo>& ptr) { return ptr.get();}};

std::vector<Foo*> bar = boost::copy_range<std::vector<Foo*>>(foo | boost::adaptors::transform(transformation()));
```

Of course you could use the `transform_iterator` from `Boost.Iterators` instead, but I find that using `Range` leads to more readable code.

Of course if you use your `vector<Foo*>` only as an argument to a function, you can skip writing it into a variable and directly call `myFunc(copy_range<std::vector<Foo*>>(...))`, which will likely enable the compiler to skip a few copies.

Comment: thanks for your answer, there are many things in your answer that I have never heard about or used, so I guess I have some learning to do.

Comment: @elelias: As mentioned my first version relies on C++11 for readability, so that is not too suprising. The c++03 version should look less alien (but also less terse), since the only strange thing about that is `Boost.Range` (which is a very nice tool to know)

Comment: There's `boost::copy_range<std::vector<T>>(foo)`, which is confusingly [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html) in the documentation.

Comment: @LucDanton: Thanks, I didn't know that. I've updated my answer accordingly.